# Term for "someone looking for sponsors"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am someone looking for sponsors. I go to potential parties or individuals who may or may not agree to sponsor and present my proposal asking for sponsorship. Who am I?

Answer (score 2):

You are a [solicitor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/solicitor):

> a person whose business it is to solicit business, trade, etc.

... just not the lawyer kind of solicitor.